# Get device info for dev file

Tags: linux, webcam, dev

This is a very simply question. I have 3 potential camera devices in `/dev/`: `video0`, `video1` and `video2`. I need to find out which one is my actual webcam and which one is a loopback device. I couldn't find any tool able to simply take any device file path and output info about it.

Does such a thing exist, or is there a better way to determine which one's my webcam?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try first to list all video devices picked up by the kernel:

```
ls -l /dev/video*
```

To list all devices attached to USB use `lsusb`,
to list all devices attached to PCI use `lspci`.

The following command-line one liner should also do so:

```
for I in /sys/class/video4linux/*; do cat $I/name; done
```

Another way is to use the
[v4l2-ctl command](https://www.mankier.com/1/v4l2-ctl)
which is part of
[v4l-utils](https://github.com/gjasny/v4l-utils)
(described in
[Introduction to v4l-utils](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/multimedia/v4l-utils.html)):

> The v4l2-ctl tool is used to control video4linux devices, either video, vbi, radio or swradio, both input and output. It is able to control almost any aspect of such devices covering the full V4L2 API.

Using it can give an output similar to:

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
HPigh Definition Webcam (usb-0000:00:14.0-11):
    /dev/video2
UVC Camera (046d:0821) (usb-0000:00:14.0-13):
    /dev/video0
Logitech Webcam C930e (usb-0000:00:14.0-9):
    /dev/video1 1.0MP H
```

Comment: Thanks! I had actually created the loopback with v4l2, but I didn't realize it could do that. Oddly, it seems like my integrated camera is both video0 and video1.